# Compiling and Running Older Dart 2.7.0 Applications After Updating to Dart 3.0.0 and Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation, migrate

I've been working on several applications in Flutter using Dart, but I initially developed them in an earlier version of Dart, specifically version 2.7.0. With the recent release of Dart 3.0.0 and the latest version of Flutter, I decided it's time to update my applications. However, after updating to Dart 3.0.0, I encountered an issue: I can no longer compile and run the applications that were developed in Dart 2.7.0.

This poses a challenge for me as there are still applications that I haven't migrated to Dart 3.0.0, and they need to be supported alongside the updated ones.

Could someone guide me on how to continue compiling and running older versions of Dart 2.7.0 applications after updating to Dart 3.0.0 and Flutter? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What errors did you get? Also you can see the [Dart 3 migration guide](https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration) and [Flutter breaking changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes).

Comment: You'll probably want "puro", a tool to help you keep multiple versions of flutter/dart installed at the same time.  See my video on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olqmK-opexA